Error en terminal al intentar compilar y servir proyecto Angular (ng serve -o)
Les consulto si saben como puedo levantar mi proyecto de Angular desde la terminal del Visual Studio Code, use el comando:
ng serve -o

Pero me larga este error:

Gracias.

Tienes que entrar a la carpeta donde tienes el proyecto, en ese mismo espacio dale cd NOMBRE_CARPETA

No, sigue todo igual, mismo error

Y si lo ejecutas fuera en la terminal?

@FacundoMSteckler puedes compartir tu package.json y la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto?

Este error:
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

Ocurre porque ng necesita encontrar los archivos de configuración y para ello la carpeta actual debe ser la raíz del proyecto.
Para resolverlo, lo que puedes hacer es hacer clic derecho en tu nombre de proyecto dentro de VSC y seleccionar la opción "Open in Integrated Terminal".
Esto abrirá la terminal con la ruta actual establecida a la raíz del proyecto y ya deberías poder ejecutar el comando ng serve -open sin ningún problema.
